# Как убрать цикл для загрузки всех изображений

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста, как правильно тут убрать цикл, чтобы можно было загружать только одно фото, не все.

```
            $this->data['id'] = $newsid;
            foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v)
            {
                $uploaddir = "tmp/news_img/";
                $apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.png';
                $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";
                if($_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/gif" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/png" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpeg")
            {
            $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4");
            foreach ($blacklist as $item)
            {
                if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['file']['name'][$k]))
            {
            $this->data['status'] = "error";
            $this->data['error'] = "Нельзя загружать скрипты.";
            }
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile))
            {
                $size = getimagesize($uploadfile);
                if ($size[0] < 1500 && $size[1] < 1500)
            {

            $news1Data = array(
                'news_id'       => $newsid,
                'image'     => $uploadfile
            );      
            $this->newsImagesModel->createImage($news1Data);
            $kk = $k+1;
            } else {
                $this->data['status'] = "error";
                $this->data['error'] = "Изображение превышает пиксили.";
                unlink($uploadfile);
            }
            } else {
            $this->data['status'] = "error";
            $this->data['error'] = "Файл не загружен.";
            }          
            } else {     
            $this->data['status'] = "error";
            $this->data['error'] = "Можно загружать только изображения в форматах jpg, jpeg, gif и png";}
            }
        } else {
            $this->data['status'] = "error";
            $this->data['error'] = $errorPOST;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Везде, где есть обращение по ключу `[$k]` убираете его и всё. А `foreach` с фигурными скобками удаляете

Плюс ещё в html форме делаете `name` без квадратных скобок